# How to use a list in a constructor in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, datatable, constructor

I want to use a `list` in another class. So my idea was to simply use a constructor, but i got a few problems. First of all i want to use the list for a `PaginatedDataTable`. Therefore I created a new class for the datasource and i want to use my list of `DataRows` in this class. Here is my constructor to get access to the list:

```
class ExerciseDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  ExerciseDataSource({Key key, this.list}) : super(key: key);
  final List<DataRow> list;
```

I got an error for using the key, saying 'The named parameter 'key' isn't defined.'

I also got an error in my class, where i have my list of DataRows named _rowList with the error 'The instance member '_rowList' can't be accessed in an initializer.':

````
class _ExerciseTableState extends State<ExerciseTable> {

  final ExerciseDataSource _rowsDataSource = ExerciseDataSource(list: _rowList);```
````

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the `List`.  Your problem is that [the base class (`DataTableSource`) constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTableSource/DataTableSource.html) does not take a named `key` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you look at the definition of `DataTableSource` you will notice it extends a`ChangeNotifier`, not a `Widget`.
2. You can't use a property of the class as a property of another property. You could modify your code to something like this:

```
class __ExerciseTableState extends State<_ExerciseTable> {
  final List _rowList = [];
  ExerciseDataSource _rowsDataSource;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _rowsDataSource = ExerciseDataSource(list: _rowList);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know if i need an extra class for the data for the PaginatedDataTable or can I just write everything in my ExerciseTable class? Would be much easier when I have everything I need in one class